# In knockout data-bind attr bind not working?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem When clicking link( tag).it contains data-bind,by using attr binding i am giving the url,and at the same time using click binding
My problem is click binding is working but not redirect the url by attr binding .
I try this code..

```
 viewModel.printbill = function () {
    var dta = ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.Bills(), function (item) {
        return item.BillID == viewModel.BillID();
    });
    if (dta != null) {
        var data = {
            List: dta
        }
        localStorage.setItem('SelectedBill', JSON.stringify(data));
    }
};
```

`<a target="_blank" title=""  data-bind='attr: {href:"@Href("~/billing/BillPrint")    "},click:printbill'>`
when clicking this link
i have a click binding:printBill,which is used to select a specific id from the button clik and map into localstorage ...all things are going good..but ..i cant redirect the screen to another tab.

Comment: What does printBill do? If it returns false, then that will stop the browser from following the link, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have both a `click` binding and an href on a link then you need to return true from the binding for the href to be followed - think of it as being able to cancel the click (and therefore the navigation).

```
 viewModel.printbill = function () {
    var dta = ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.Bills(), function (item) {
        return item.BillID == viewModel.BillID();
    });
    if (dta != null) {
        var data = {
            List: dta
        }
        localStorage.setItem('SelectedBill', JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    return true; // <---- here
};
```

Comment: its coming like pop up ...i want open that url in new tab in current browser...what can i do for this?

Comment: you have `target="_blank"` in your link. thats why its opening a new window

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the link use button to Redirect and click